# Applicablity of multipole-expansion (ME)

Tags: multipole-expansion

I have three questions about applicability of ME from nerdy physicists:

1. Is Multipole-Expansion a general mathematical decomposition tool? or it is only applicable in physics? (physics = gravity, electrostatic, electromagnetic, radiation, ...).
2. if it is a general mathematical tool, could we apply it to other problems? (any problem that includes interaction of $N*N$ objects)?
3. if so, what are requirements or principles of applying ME or Fast-Multiple-method in other (non-physics) problems? I can guess presence of "translation" is a crucial concept, i mean there should be meaning and ability to translate multi-poles to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Multipole expansion is a series expansion for functions of two angles. The basis of the series is made of spherical harmonics $~Y^{m}_{l}( \theta , \varphi ) ~$.
   It has nothing to do with clustering.

$$f( \theta , \varphi )= \sum_{m=0}^ \infty  \sum_{m=-l}^ l a_{m,l} Y^{m}_{l}( \theta , \varphi ) $$

1. The only requirement is that the integrals for the coefficients exist.
   $$a_{m,l}= \int_0^ {2\pi}   \int_0^ {2\pi} f( \theta , \varphi ) (Y^{m}_{l})^{*}( \theta , \varphi )d \Omega $$
2. Common tool in quantum mechanics and heat flow calculation.
3. You are looking for a function of two angles.

Answer (score 0):

1. ME is used in Physics as a way for approximating the influence of a cluster of "neighboring systems" to points far from them, but it could be as a general mathematical method for approximating sum of functions, decaying as the the independent variables increase
2. I guess so, as far as the assumptions to get a good approximation by this method holds
3. In FMMs you need two expansions, namely a multipole expansion, and a local expansion. You need:

   - a way to find cluster (or divide your domain) using a "distance criterion"
   - a way to evaluate multipole expansion at the finest level of the domain partition
   - a way to translate multipole expansion from the finest level to coarser level of the grid partition
   - a way to convert multipole expansion to local expansion
   - a way to translate local expansion from the coarsest to the finest level of the grid partition.

All these steps are well explained in the references I leave you here about Fast Multiple Methods, you can easily find on google:

- *Introduction to fast multipole methods*, Chen
- *A short course on fast multipole methods*, Beatson and Greengard

Comment: A spherical function has these properties, the only thing i need is a function with 2 parameters (as @Shaktyai says) and a space partitioning technique.